# Multi Threading, Task.Run Error 'The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties'

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, ambiguous

When I try to build project the following error message is displayed.

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(System.Action)' and
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(System.Func)'

How can i fix this?

```
public static class MaintananceManager
    {
        private static ThreadSafeSocialMediaList<Post> PostList = new ThreadSafeSocialMediaList<Post>();
        private static ThreadSafeSocialMediaList<SocialUser> SocialUserList = new ThreadSafeSocialMediaList<SocialUser>();

        private static List<IPersistentProvider> providers = new List<IPersistentProvider>();
        private const int CACHESIZE = 1000;

        static MaintananceManager()
        {
            providers.Add(new SqlServerProvider());
            Task.Run(startMaintaining);

        }
        public static void PersistPosts(IEnumerable<Post> posts) 
        {
            PostList.AddRange(posts);
        }
        public static void PersistSocialUsers(IEnumerable<SocialUser> users)
        {
            SocialUserList.AddRange(users);
        }

        public static SocialUser GetSocialUser(SocialMediaType mediaType,string socialMediaId)
        {
            foreach(var provider in providers)
            {
                try
                {
                    return provider.GetSocialUser(mediaType, socialMediaId);
                }
                catch
                {

                }

            }
            return null;
        }
        private static void persistPosts()
        {
            var liste = PostList.Flush();
            foreach(var provider in providers)
            {
                provider.SavePosts(liste);
            }
        }
        private static void persistUsers()
        {
            var liste = SocialUserList.Flush();
            foreach (var provider in providers)
            {
                provider.SaveSocialUsers(liste);
            }
        }
        private static void startMaintaining()
        {
            while(true)
            {
                if (PostList.Count > CACHESIZE)
                    persistPosts();
                if (SocialUserList.Count > CACHESIZE)
                    persistUsers();

                Thread.Sleep(60000);

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: If you are in .Net 4.5+, which I think you do, you could avoid to hog the threadpool thread that executes the maintenance routine and get better overall performance by changing its signature from `private static void startMaintaining()` to `private static Task startMaintaining()` and replacing `Thread.Sleep(60000);` by `await Task.Delay(60000).ConfigureAwait(false);` to fully take advantage of TPL.

Comment: also you need it to be async to be able to use await

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There's a few ways you could pass this as a valid `Action`:

```
Task.Run(() => startMaintaining());

Task.Run((Action)startMaintaining);

Task.Run(new Action(startMaintaining));
```